# I'm getting a ValueError: unable to convert str to float 'XX'

Tags: python, pandas, string, scikit-learn, valueerror

Some background, I'm taking a machine learning class on customer segmentation. My code env is pandas(python) and sklearn. I have two datasets, a general population dataset and a customer demographics dataset with 85 identical columns.

I'm calling a function I created to run preprocessing steps on the 'customers' data, steps that were previously run outside this function on the general population dataset. Within the function is a loop that replaces missing values with np.nan. Here is the loop:

```py
#replacing missing data with NaNs.
#feat_sum is a dataframe (feature_summary) of coded values

    for i in range(len(feat_sum)):
        mi_unk = feat_sum.iloc[i]['missing_or_unknown'] #locate column and values
        mi_unk = mi_unk.strip('[').strip(']').split(',')# strip the brackets then split
        mi_unk = [int(val) if (val!='' and val!='X' and val!='XX') else val for val in mi_unk]
    if mi_unk != ['']:
        featsum_attrib = feat_sum.iloc[i]['attribute']
        df = df.replace({featsum_attrib: mi_unk}, np.nan)
```

Toward the end of the function I'm engineering new variables:

```py
#Investigate "CAMEO_INTL_2015" and engineer two new variables.

    df['WEALTH'] = df['CAMEO_INTL_2015']
    df['LIFE_STAGE'] = df['CAMEO_INTL_2015']

    mf_wealth_dict = {'11':1, '12':1, '13':1, '14':1, '15':1, '21':2, '22':2, '23':2, '24':2, '25':2, '31':3,'32':3, '33':3, '34':3, '35':3, '41':4, '42':4, '43':4, '44':4, '45':4, '51':5, '52':5, '53':5, '54':5, '55':5}

    mf_lifestage_dict = {'11':1, '12':2, '13':3, '14':4, '15':5, '21':1, '22':2, '23':3, '24':4, '25':5, '31':1, '32':2, '33':3, '34':4, '35':5, '41':1, '42':2, '43':3, '44':4, '45':5, '51':1, '52':2,  '53':3, '54':4, '55':5}

#replacing the 'WEALTH' and 'LIFE_STAGE' columns with values from the dictionaries

    df['WEALTH'].replace(mf_wealth_dict, inplace=True)
    df['LIFE_STAGE'].replace(mf_lifestage_dict, inplace=True)
```

Near the end of the project code, I'm running an imputer to replace the np.nans which ran successfully on the general population dataset(azdias):

```
az_imp = Imputer(strategy="most_frequent")
azdias_cleaned_imp = pd.DataFrame(az_imp.fit_transform(azdias_cleaned_encoded))
```

So when I call the clean_data function passing the 'customers' dataframe, clean_data(customers),it is giving me the ValueError: could not convert str to float: 'XX' on this line:

```
     customers_imp = Imputer(strategy="most_frequent")
---> 19 customers_cleaned_imputed = pd.DataFrame(customers_imp.fit_transform(customers_cleaned_encoded))
```

In the data dictionary for the `CAMEO_INTL_2015` column of the dataset, the very last category is 'XX': unknown. When I run a value count on the `WEALTH` and `LIFE_STAGE` columns, 124 occurrences of 'XX' under those two columns. No other columns in the dataset have the 'XX' value except these.  Again, no issues with the other dataset, I did not run into this problem.  I know this is wordy, but any help appreciated and I can provide the project code as well.

A mentor and myself tried troubleshooting looking at all the steps that were performed on both datasets, to no avail. I was expecting the 'XX' to be dealt with from the loop I mentioned earlier.

Comment: It's really hard to follow the question. Try and simplify it in a way that is an isolated problem. It would be better to remove the lengthy introduction about your project/assignment. Also, if you can share the dataset that is causing the problem it would help people to reproduce the issue.